# VR Unity splash freezes with large scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I start an app that the first scene contains too much data, after 3 seconds the Unity splash is like "frozen"... By this way, if I move my head to see any part of the VR world, all is black.
I can only see a rectangle area with the unity logo from the splash, but the remaining space is black.

I suppose that it occurs because all data of the scene are being loading, but, is there anyway to avoid this problem?

I'm using a Gear VR and a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

Check this image to see that the user see if move their head after the splash is "frozen":

[image: black areas]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly am I looking at in that picture? Is that cut off blue triangle the screen of the device?

Comment: If your first scene is empty except for a script that immediately loads some other scene, does that help at all? I've seen that help with certain Unity initialization problems in the past.

Comment: @code11 the picture shows that the user is viewing through the Gear VR. While the next scene is being loaded, the VR environment is black and I don't want that.

Comment: @rutter thanks for the tip... tomorrow I'll test it.